# WebView in fragment - other fragments work well but this causes the app to crash

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, webview, android-studio-4.0

Can you tell me what's wrong in my code and why webview doesn't work? Other fragments work well but this one crashes the whole app. I have many fragments with videoView and they work. This one should display a web page but I can't make it to work. Here is my code:

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context=".Trz">


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

KT

```
package com.tester.testing

import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.webkit.WebView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_second.*

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass as the second destination in the navigation.
 */
class Trz : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false)
        val myWebView: WebView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview)
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com")
return rootView
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: Can you copy paste the error you re getting when the app crashes ?